# Hide field in pivot chart only when connected to pivot table

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, pivot-table

I searched and didn't find an answer I am afraid, maybe its not possible to achieve the below and I not fully understand the concept but I'd like to make sure.
I have a pivot-chart which is connected to a pivot-table and as you can see in the picture below the fields are linked. 
How can I hide the "Diff" in the chart only without it being hidden in the pivot-table? Its just a displaying thing so I hope that this is somehow possible without disconnecting the chart from the pivot-table as I want it to be continuously updated when the data changes.

Edit: Found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/695036/how-do-i-create-a-pivotchart-from-a-subset-of-pivottable-data) that suggests that this is not possible without copying the original table. Can someone confirm that there is no more elegant way of achieving this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot chart will always display all of the data that is visible in the pivot table. If you don't want to show "Diff" in the chart, don't include it in the PT. If you want to show the Diff field in a Pivot table, let the chart refer to a different pivot table that you create exclusively for the chart.

With Excel 2010 and above you can use slicers to connect the filter settings for different pivot tables, so you can filter the pivot table and the same filters will be applied to the pivot chart's underlying table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer even when I hoped that this is not the case. Will make a copy then.